# Typescript object literal "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, typescript, this, object-literal

What's the expected behavior when using `this` inside a function in an object literal?

For example, let's say I have a type `foo` that only has a function named `bar` and no other property on it. But in the `fooObj.bar` method, I'm able to access `this.baz` (where `baz` is not a property on type `foo`) I see no error. Shouldn't typescript error out, as `fooObj` does not have `baz` on it?

```
type foo = {
    bar(): void;
}
var fooObj: foo = {
    bar: () => {
        // TS does not error out when I access this.baz
        console.log(this.baz);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `"noImplicitThis":true` compiler option?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Setting the `"noImplicitThis": true` compiler option is how you would enable this functionality now. [This pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/14141) enabled typed `this` in object literals. Aleksey L originally suggested this compiler option in a comment on the question, but at the time it didn't function that way.

Comment: This is the actual solution. `noImplicitThis` makes the `this` keyword work the way that you would expect, in an object literal.

Answer (score 3):

You’re using an arrow function, [which has lexical `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this).

The shorthand for a non-arrow function property in an object literal is even shorter, though:

```
var fooObj: foo = {
    bar() {
        console.log(this.baz);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question remains: What is `baz` and why isn't TypeScript telling you that `foo` (which should be the type of `this` I think) doesn't have a `baz` property? I'm not super knowledgable about TypeScript, but isn't the whole point that your types need to explicitly define their properties? I guess the question is, why is `this` of type `any` inside a lexically bound function, and not of type `foo`?

Comment: @meagar: `foo` shouldn’t be the type of `this`. `this` will be whatever `this` was in the function containing the object literal.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I glossed over the fact that we're not in an ES6 class declaration. Why then, does TypeScript not look at the context of the object literal declaration and see that whatever type `this` is still doesn't have a `baz` property?

Comment: @meagar Because `this` is the global scope in that code, which is `any`.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the subtleties of using an arrow function. But even when I try using non-arrow function, "this" resolves to "any" as opposed to foo. This allows for access to properties that are not defined inside the object literal.

Answer (score 3):

**This answer was true at the time of the question. This have since changed with new versions of typescript and target javascript versions.**

You are asking typescript to infer that `this` is `fooObj`.

Typescript binds `this` by creating a local variable `_this`, that is bound to the `this`-context where the fat-arrow is declared. And in your case, `this` is the global scope, which is `any`. This is what it gets compiled into:

```
var _this = this;
var fooObj = {
    bar: function () {
        // TS does not error out when I access this.baz
        console.log(_this.baz);
    }
};
```

This is how it looks like within a class:

```
class Bar
{
    private var = 23;
    public makeSound = () => console.log(this.var) 
}

// Compiles into:

var Bar = (function () {
    function Bar() {
        var _this = this;
        this.var = 23;
        this.makeSound = function () { return console.log(_this.var); };
    }
    return Bar;
}());
```